# How to sort custom sortable column by custom table value

Tags: php, custom-post-types, wp-query, actions, columns

I have a custom table with data in it that I am showing in a column. I would like to make this column sortable.

Lets say that the custom table has **three** values for the sake of simplicity.

`row_id, post_id, value`

Where, **post_id** is the id of a post somwhere on the site.

Now in that post types custom column I show the `value` of the new table, and I would like to sort the the column by that `value`.

The way I have been trying to do it is to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the 'join' of the WP_query. (I have tried on pre_get_posts action and the post_clauses action.)

However I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while.

How would you go about sorting the column by the data found in this custom table? **(Without resorting to meta values)**

Let me know if that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the solution is to use the `posts_clauses` filter.

Lets assume we have 2 values in our custom table that we will call `custom_table` that we want to sort by one **bigint** that we will call `value` and one **text** that we will call `text`.

In order to sort, we need to ensure that we have a common value in the table that can be used to join onto the main posts table. So for that we will use a third value in the table that we will call `post_id`. This value needs to match with a corresponding ID of what ever post you are referring too. For now we are going to be using the `post` post type.

I am sure this will can be expanded upon further, but that is what I went with for our simple example.

First lets start by adding the filter:

`add_filter('posts_clauses', 'custom_sort_columns_clauses', 10, 2);`

Then lets create our function

```
function custom_sort_columns_clauses($clauses, $query)
{
    // Ensure we are in admin and querying
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $clauses;
    }
    global $wpdb; //Get our global variable to gain access to our database prefix
    //Value order
    if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'post' && $query->get( 'orderby' ) === 'Value' ) 
    {
        $clauses['join'] .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table ON {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table.post_id";
        $clauses['orderby'] = "{$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table.value " . $query -> get('order');
    }
    //Alphabetical order
    if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'post' && $query-> get('orderby') === 'Text' )
    {
        $clauses['join'] .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table ON {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table.post_id";
        $clauses['orderby'] = "{$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table.text " . $query -> get('order');
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

Lets break down the sauce.

`if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'post' && $query->get( 'orderby' ) === 'Value' )`

This ensures that we have the right orderby that we are working on. Notice the **Value** This should match what you see in your URL. For example:

> edit.php?orderby=**Value**&order=asc

If it were:

> edit.php?orderby=**value**&order=asc

use lowercase instead or what ever exists there to ensure you are working on the right orderby.

After that:

`$clauses['join'] .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table ON {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table.post_id";`

What we are doing here is using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` SQL function to join both tables together (I use outer just in case there are nulls, but if you know there won't be you don't need OUTER). where `posts.ID` = `custom_table.post_id`

After that we need to change our order by to use our custom_table value.

we do that with:

`$clauses['orderby'] = "{$wpdb -> prefix}custom_table.value " . $query -> get('order');`

I use the `$query -> get('order')` to ensure that the direction matches our query order. i.e **ASC** or **DESC**.

Then after we have done with all our clauses we need to return our clauses with:

`return $clauses` remembering that `$clauses` is one of our parameters that we pass to the hook.

I hope that this helps anyone who had the same problem as I.

I am not really a pro programmer and only do it because I like creating things, so any edits to make this better I would love to hear!